# Help identify this unknown piece - black police torso, but it has the LEGO logo printed on the middle of the front

Tags: part-identification

I've been looking on Bricklink for a while now, but I haven't found this piece yet, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what it is based on its description: it's a black police torso, but it has the LEGO logo printed on the middle of the front of the torso.

[image: black police torso, but it has the LEGO logo printed on the middle of the front]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! I'm not familiar with a torso that fits that description. It may be helpful to add a photo to your question to help folks better identify this element.

Comment: Oddly enough, "Lego" is a difficult word to use to search for these things :-) To save others from searching, my googling for **torso "lego pattern"** and **torso "lego and" pattern** have not found it. Though there are some cool Lego House and Lego World 2012 torsos on BrickLink. A picture is definitely the way to go, here.

Comment: Here's a picture of the piece, still not sure what it is on Bricklink

Comment: Oh, I think I found it. It's from this keychain https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=101212

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is either from 2011's [Flashlight, Dynamo Torch - Motor Police](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=dyntorch4) (which is *not* a minifig but rather a 20cm-high figurine with a flashlight inside a leg, and a crank in a shoulder)...

[image: dynamo flashlight]

...or, as user @bgeorge has pointed out in a comment, [Mini Torch Minifigure Flashlight Key Chain Police](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=kclight04)

[image: keychain flashlight]

Keep in mind that [keychain minifigs are different from standard minifigs](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10898/), and so the torso cannot be separated from the legs or head.